# How to reinstall grub / remount /boot/efi on a running system? Linux Mint 20.2

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint, dualboot

I'm new to linux and I've installed Linux Mint 20.2 as dual-boot on a new SSD / NvMe device. Windows 10 was still installed on a existing SSD. Turned out i've missed creating and extra partition for /boot/efi - which now still resides on the old SSD.. i'm sure this is an easy question for you folks out there:

How can I install grub or /boot/efi on my first partition on /dev/nvme0n1p1, where /boot already is ? Does it work as ext4 ?

Here a dump of my fstab & blkid:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

UUID=dbb9d17c-da59-4c67-a8bc-d1c0376d25d1   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
UUID=788f6c5a-b9fb-4bc3-bb33-5462ad839a6a   /boot   ext4    defaults    0   2
UUID=788f6c5a-b9fb-4bc3-bb33-5462ad839a6a   /boot/efi   ext4    umask=0077  0   1
UUID=2e1f5f01-22d6-4729-8cb9-afa8febe8f0c   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=F648EC1248EBCF83   none    ntfs    defaults    0   0


$ blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="788f6c5a-b9fb-4bc3-bb33-5462ad839a6a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="248a5c3f-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="2e1f5f01-22d6-4729-8cb9-afa8febe8f0c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="248a5c3f-05"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="dbb9d17c-da59-4c67-a8bc-d1c0376d25d1" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="248a5c3f-06"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="A078E05578E02C2A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="dd858f7c-8e98-4da9-bf02-0c6c39a03894"
/dev/sda2: UUID="20E1-2C98" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b0e2ea1b-8deb-4c5b-8f2b-4447ef73c4ac"
/dev/sda4: UUID="F648EC1248EBCF83" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8d55df99-9d08-437d-859b-087830d311e0"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL_FATBOOT="VeraCrypt" LABEL="VeraCrypt" UUID="FC12-7105" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="9b3dbd4e-2ecf-48c7-802a-1750a00a7fc7"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="5990a595-dddf-4426-88a9-4c524f6158e8" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="9430b710-f2ca-4a01-97eb-2904bc2e5747"
/dev/mapper/luks-5990a595-dddf-4426-88a9-4c524f6158e8: LABEL="Encrypted" UUID="1de7f161-56cd-4bea-951d-2fcb91bd5712" TYPE="ext4"
```

Thanks for any help !
Have a great day

Comment: You don't normally create a separate efi partition for Linux or any other operating system, they all use the same one... However, sometimes it isn't large enough and needs to increased in size. Boot your install media and run Boot Repair, it's an application in the menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to get rid of windows and this extra harddisk and have everything in one place, looking forward for advice on how to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by unmounting the existing /boot/efi partition, creating the /efi folder in /boot and copying the contents in there.

Then I changed my /etc/fstab where I just deleted the entry for the /boot/efi partition